# Make line along edge of several rasters

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I'll try to keep this simple.

Is there a way to make a polyline that runs along the edge of these polygons. It is cadastrals that assembly the coastline and I need to generate a line that works as the outer boundary.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `dissolve` your polygons and then either style the dissolved polygon as you like to display the outline, or convert it to a line-feature and style that accordingly.